# How to Create a Multiple Choice Android List View with result gotten from Mysql database using PHP?

Tags: php, android, mysql, xml, listview

i have gone through numerous ariticles both on google and here at stack overflow,but i can't seem to find a solution to my problem.The code fragment i'm about to place below is a tutorial i studied and decided to expand it.I have tried converting the listview to a multiple choice listview,but can't seem to go around that.I don't want to create a custom adapter with a layout containing a checkbox as it would be more complicated for me.

```
public class AllProductsActivity extends ListActivity {

    // Progress Dialog
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    // Creating JSON Parser object
    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> productsList;

    // url to get all products list
    private static String url_all_products = "http://10.180.35.102/android_connect/get_all_products.php";

    // JSON Node names
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String TAG_PRODUCTS = "products";
    private static final String TAG_PID = "pid";
    private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
    private static final String TAG_PRICE="price";

    // products JSONArray
    JSONArray products = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.all_products);



        // Hashmap for ListView
        productsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        // Loading products in Background Thread
        new LoadAllProducts().execute();

        // Get listview
        ListView lv = getListView();

        // on seleting single product
        // launching Edit Product Screen
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {
                // getting values from selected ListItem
                String pid = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.pid)).getText()
                        .toString();

                // Starting new intent
                Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        EditProductActivity.class);
                // sending pid to next activity
                in.putExtra(TAG_PID, pid);

                // starting new activity and expecting some response back
                startActivityForResult(in, 100);
            }
        });

    }



    // Response from Edit Product Activity
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        // if result code 100
        if (resultCode == 100) {
            // if result code 100 is received
            // means user edited/deleted product
            // reload this screen again
            Intent intent = getIntent();
            finish();
            startActivity(intent);
        }

    }

    /**
     * Background Async Task to Load all product by making HTTP Request
     * */
    class LoadAllProducts extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */

/**         @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(AllProductsActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading products. Please wait...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }
**/

        /**
         * getting All products from url
         * */
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            // getting JSON string from URL
            JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_products, "GET", params);

            // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
            Log.d("All Products: ", json.toString());

            try {
                // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                if (success == 1) {
                    // products found
                    // Getting Array of Products
                    products = json.getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCTS);

                    // looping through All Products
                    for (int i = 0; i < products.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = products.getJSONObject(i);

                        // Storing each json item in variable
                        String id = c.getString(TAG_PID);
                        String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                        String price = c.getString(TAG_PRICE);

                        // creating new HashMap
                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                        map.put(TAG_PID, id);
                        map.put(TAG_NAME, name);
                        map.put(TAG_PRICE, price);

                        // adding HashList to ArrayList
                        productsList.add(map);
                    }
                } else {
                    // no products found
                    // Launch Add New product Activity
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                            NewProductActivity.class);
                    // Closing all previous activities
                    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
      //      pDialog.dismiss();
            // updating UI from Background Thread
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    /**
                     * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
                     * */
                    ListAdapter  adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                            AllProductsActivity.this, productsList,
                           R.layout.list_item, new String[] { TAG_PID,
                            TAG_NAME,TAG_PRICE},
                            new int[] { R.id.pid, R.id.name, R.id.price });
                    // updating listview
                    setListAdapter(adapter);
                   //getListView().setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
                }
            });


        }
```

Here is the xml layout for list_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <!-- Product id (pid) - will be HIDDEN - used to pass to other activity -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/pid"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <!-- Name Label -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="6dip"
        android:paddingLeft="6dip"
        android:textSize="17dip"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        />
    <!---price label-->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/price"

        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/name"
        android:paddingTop="6dip"
        android:paddingLeft="6dip"
        android:textSize="9dip"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is the Xml layout for all products

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <!-- Main ListView
         Always give id value as list(@android:id/list)
    -->
    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       />

</LinearLayout>
```

Please how can i add the multiple choice check list to this code.I will greatly appreciate any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Writing a custom adapter would be the proper way to deal this issue, because then you are more flexible (see: [Model-View-Control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller)). However, if you are not in the mood for this solution, you can simply inflate manually a [checkbox](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CheckBox.html) view for each item of the productsList.

```
protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {           
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            ViewGroup list = findViewById(R.id.list);

            for(Map map : productsList){
                ViewGroup parent = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.id.list_item, null);

                CheckBox cbview = new CheckBox(getContext);
                //setup the cbview with the necessary attributes from map                    

                parent.addView(cbview);

                list.addView(parent);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot of the imediate responds.@SME_Dev please i'm getting an error "cannot resolve symbol at (R.id.list) and (R.id.list_item).Please What should i do?

Answer (score 1):

Maintain 2 boolean variable arrays one is temporary and another as class member once user click the checkbox ok button then store it in class variable.

As Code is given for loading values user confirmed by ok button.

```
     void showMyMultipleChoiceDialog()
    {
    final boolean[] sel1 = new boolean[allusers.size()];
    for (int i = 0; i < sel.length; i++)
    {
        sel1[i] = sel[i];
    }
    AlertDialog.Builder builderMultiple = new AlertDialog.Builder(DetailsTaskIncompleteActivity.this);
    builderMultiple.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    builderMultiple.setTitle("Select Users");

    builderMultiple.setMultiChoiceItems(userlist, sel1, new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which, boolean isChecked)
        {

        }
    });
    builderMultiple.setPositiveButton("Done", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id)
        {
            // users.delete(0, users.length());
            for (int i = 0; i < sel.length; i++)
            {
                sel[i] = false;
            }
            users.setLength(1);
            for (int i = 0; i < sel1.length; i++)
            {
                if (sel1[i] == true)
                {
                    users.append(userlist[i] + ",");
                    sel[i] = true;
                }
            }
        }
    });


    builderMultiple.show();
    }
```